# Refactor this Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I need to refactor this code so that the data service wont query two workTypes per row item. Thanks in advance.

```
        _attributeGroups = attributeGroups.Select(attributeGroupRowModel =>
            new AttributeGroupRowModel()
        {
            Name = attributeGroupRowModel.Name,               
            WorkType = workTypes.First(wt => wt.Id == attributeGroupRowModel.WorkTypeId).Description,
            IsExpired = workTypes.First(wt => wt.Id == attributeGroupRowModel.WorkTypeId).IsExpired, //todo: not efficient, to be refactored
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
_attributeGroups = attributeGroups.Select(attributeGroupRowModel => 
{
    var wt = workTypes.First(x => x.Id == attributeGroupRowModel.WorkTypeId);
    return new AttributeGroupRowModel()
    {
        Name = attributeGroupRowModel.Name,               
        WorkType = wt.Description,
        IsExpired = wt.IsExpired,
    };
}).ToList();
```

or if you prefer LINQ:

```
_attributeGroups = 
    (from attributeGroupRowModel in attributeGroups
     let wt = workTypes.First(x => x.Id == attributeGroupRowModel.WorkTypeId)
     select new AttributeGroupRowModel()
     {
         Name = attributeGroupRowModel.Name,               
         WorkType = wt.Description,
         IsExpired = wt.IsExpired,
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: I actually tried the first one before I posted here, I just realized that my error is the same as yours, the freaking semi colon after return lol :)

Comment: actually the first one i saw has no semicolon on the return (or it just been delayed because you were too fast), anyway thanks man;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [statement lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) instead of an expression lambda. A statement lambda allows you, among other things, to define variables:

```
_attributeGroups = attributeGroups.Select(attributeGroupRowModel => 
{
    var w = workTypes.First(wt => wt.Id == attributeGroupRowModel.WorkTypeId);
    return new AttributeGroupRowModel()
    {
        Name = attributeGroupRowModel.Name,               
        WorkType = w.Description,
        IsExpired = w.IsExpired,
    };
}).ToList();
```